# Whitelisting MSBuild SafeImports (Project Files that have MSBuild customisations that are trusted)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, msbuild

Visual Studio 2008  `devenv` keeps a list of projects for which one has answered `Load project normally` in the `Security Warning for` ProjectName ... `The ProjectName project file has been customised and could present a security risk by executing custom build steps...` dialog in the registry at: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0\MSBuild\SafeImports`

Is there any way to e.g. add a wildcard whitelist entry and/or disable this security warning on a global basis, (ideally via a VS Tools|Options dialog page) ?

PS For bingoogleability:- OR `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0\MSBuild\SafeImports`

PS I believe VS2010 cures this and there's a VS2005 era connect issue where people were going to make msbuild files signeable etc, but I'm on 08 for the moment.

(NB There's a duplicate question or two which conflate issues of untrusted locations and wacky startup directories. This is not that complex case - I am adding a single normal unblocked .csproj into a normal unblocked .sln which happens to Import something from the same normally permissioned directory tree structure. I'm only interested in this simplest case of this condition.)

Comment: Have you found an answer to your problem? I got an .props file which I want to include but the path is relative and so I can not define it in regedit.

Comment: @yohannesdedope No, sorry - not sure if behavior has changed in VS2012 or whether I'm not doing the same sort of thing but I'm definitely not getting it on a regular enough basis to say!

Comment: Nope, I get the same error in VS2012